# WCF generate proxy classes with namespace as it is in server side

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, namespaces

I have below class:

```
namespace ESF.Engine.SharedObjects.CatalogManagement
{
    [DataContract()]
    public class Customer
    {
        private string _LastName;

        private System.DateTime _BirthDate;

        private decimal _MoneyInCash;

        private bool _IsActive;

        private string _AdditionalInfo;

        private decimal _ITEMID;

        private string _NAME;

        [DataMember()]
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._LastName;
            }
            set
            {
                this._LastName = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public System.DateTime BirthDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this._BirthDate;
            }
            set
            {
                this._BirthDate = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public decimal MoneyInCash
        {
            get
            {
                return this._MoneyInCash;
            }
            set
            {
                this._MoneyInCash = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public bool IsActive
        {
            get
            {
                return this._IsActive;
            }
            set
            {
                this._IsActive = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string AdditionalInfo
        {
            get
            {
                return this._AdditionalInfo;
            }
            set
            {
                this._AdditionalInfo = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public decimal ITEMID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ITEMID;
            }
            set
            {
                this._ITEMID = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this._NAME;
            }
            set
            {
                this._NAME = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding Service Reference, the proxy for this class generated under namespace which is default for client application.

Is it possible to force the class proxy to be generated as it is in server?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: use `/n:*,%NAMESPACE%` argument for `svcutil` where %NAMESPACE% is your desired namespace

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to do the same with VS UpdateService Reference?